# trying to integrate php with jade

Tags: php, pug

the following is my code.

```
li(class = "home", class = "<?php if($page == 'home'){echo '.on';} ?>")
```

i need a result as

```
<li class="home <?php if($page == 'home'){echo '.on';} ?> "></li>
```

but its turning out as

```
<li class="home #{&lt;?php if($page == 'home'){echo '.on';} ?&gt;}"></li>
```

any one has any suggestions

tried !{} but no luck

fyi: using atom as editor and xampp as server

Comment: I don't know Atom, but https://atom.io/packages/transform makes it look like there are some built-in text transformations. In particular there is one called `escapeHTML` that looks like it might be the ticket.

Comment: Thank you buck54321, but i got the solution. it was just my lack of knowledge. li(class = 'home', class != "<?php if($page == 'home'){echo 'on';} ?>") does the work.